# Get task args if hard timelimit exceeded

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

Is it possible to get task info if HardTimeLimit occured?
Also in the following situation

```
@app.task(soft_time_limit=9, max_retries=0, time_limit=10)
def task():
     try:
        do_something()
     except SoftTimeLimit:
        return
```

is it possible that TimeLimitExceeded is raised? If yes, how can I catch it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible as the default time is 300s.

To catch you can use this:

```
except TimeLimitExceeded:
    return
```

And if you want to increase default time you can modify your `celery (/etc/init.d/celeryd)` settings. The sample below sets the time limit to 1 hour.

```
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=3600 -E --loglevel=DEBUG"
```